# I installed XCode 4.3 from the app store, now I can't run iOS Simulator without launching XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I routinely need to run the iOS simulator, and I prefer to run it from Spotlight.

When I installed XCode 4.3 from the mac app store, it prompted me to remove the /Developer folder, which I accepted. Now Spotlight doesn't list the iOS Simulator app in the results so I assume it was deleted with /Developer....

How do I run the iOS simulator now?
Thanks!

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that if you're using Alfred (which is an extended version of spotlight) you can drag the simulator into Alfred's search scope and it will appear in the search results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure Spotlight will ever find it again, it's now embedded inside Xcode.app:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/
```

I launched it once via Xcode and then opted to keep it in the dock. Alternatively I guess you could try copying / symlinking it into the /Applications directory and see if spotlight picks it up.

Comment: Thank you, the symlink works and I added it to my Dock.  Spotlight still doesn't find the symlink but this is better than launching XCode!

Answer (score 1):

The simulator is embedded in the Xcode app at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications

When it is running, right-click on the icon in the doc and select Options:Keep In Dock, then it is a click away.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator is embedded in the Xcode.app bundle. From the iOS SDK ReleaseNotes:

> Within Xcode, you can launch additional developer tools, such as Instruments and FileMerge, via the menu item Xcode -> Open Developer Tool. You can then pin the tool on your Dock for access when Xcode is not running.

Spotlight will probably not index it because it's in the bundle, but might index the link to it in the dock. Otherwise try creating a symlink somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait until Spotlight reindexed. iOS Simulator is still a standalone program.